# QT SQLite Store data structures upload?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, data-structures

Hello I'm new to using qt or SQLite so I'm learning as I go. anyways I'm working on a project in which I will define an object which will then go into a data structure and I would like to upload such data structure into mySQlite database, I don't know if this is possible or can anyone point me out in the right direction to accomplish something like this?

Comment: You could serialize your class to xml and put the xml into a database field. Or are you looking to do orm like this http://www.qxorm.com/qxorm_en/home.html

Comment: With that said I would not recommend either if you are new with Qt and sqlite. I think these will be way over your level at this time.